# How do the protocols used in Ethereum (e.g. Whisper, P2P protocol suite) map onto the OSI model?

Tags: network, whisper, devp2p, p2pool, rlpx

It would be useful to have a mapping of all of the protocols involved with the Ethereum implementations on to the [OSI model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OSI_model) (or equivalent). The protocols might include:

[Whisper](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/Whisper-Overview), [devP2P](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/%C3%90%CE%9EVp2p-Wire-Protocol), IPC, RPC, ABI, Wire, [RLPx](https://github.com/ethereum/devp2p/blob/master/rlpx.md)

This would help new users quickly get an understanding of the function of each protocol/application and assess what the options are (if any) within each layer.

**How do the protocols used in the Ethereum implementation map onto the OSI model?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
| OSI Layer    | Ethereum Protocols |
-------------------------------------
| Application  | Kademlia, RPC, IPC |

| Presentation | AES, ECDSA         |

| Session      |                    |

| Transport    |                    |

| Network      |                    |

| Data Link    |                    |

| Physical     |                    |
```

Please note that there is always an ambiguity/argument about the exact mappings to OSI layer. Each protocol works/can work at different layers and cannot be exactly matched to an OSI layer. The OSI layer can sometimes make life easy but it should not be used as a reference for everything.