# Classification of the information flows and protocols within the Ethereum platform

Tags: blockchain, consensus, devp2p, user-experience, governance

I've been attempting to classify the information flows and protocols within the Ethereum system. To do this, I [extended the OSI model](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/70713/44807) to include 4 extra layers: consensus (the algorithm by which consensus is achieved amoungst computers), user interface, social, and governance.

The below is an intial effort based, in part, on [this answer](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/9923/820).

```
| Layer        | Ethereum Blockchain Protocols                               |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------

| Governance   | EIP process, Influencer announcements and social consensus  |

| Social       | Github, Reddit, SE, Slack, Word of Mouth etc                |

| UX/UI        | Geth, Parity, PyEthApp, Mist                                |

| Consensus    | Block derivation and PoW (Yellow Paper)                     |

| Application  | Kademlia, RPC, IPC                                          |

| Presentation | AES, ECDSA                                                  |

| Session      |                                                             |

| Transport    | DevP2P, RLPx, TCP                                           |

| Network      | As public internet                                          |

| Data Link    | As public internet                                          |

| Physical     | As public internet                                          |
```

Are there any ommisions or incorrect entries?

Does something like this already exist?

Would you change the upper 4 layers?

What other ways of doing it are there?

Comment: This might be suitable for framing :-) Possibly outside the scope of your project but I'll throw the idea out there anyway. I can see an opportunity to insert some layers above your UX/UI ... web3 API ... and above that, nodejs, python, browser single-page app. Possibly UX/UI is a lower-level app interface to "state", web3 is an API, apps talk to web3, and servers/clients talk to users. I like how the model continues "up" the stack to social and governance. This could be a valuable resource. .

Comment: @RobHitchens thanks. I think I'd put nodejs/web3/browser interface in UI/UX - it could perhaps be graded from application-interface to human(ai) interface. Things to do with "state" I'd provisionally put in the consensus layer. I'll give it some more thought.

Comment: I always thought DevP2P and RLPx were application layer (or session - do they maintain sessions?), and that everything (except UDP-based node discovery) was TCP. (I think..?)

Comment: Do Geth, Parity and PyEthApp deserve to be UX/UI? I'm thinking in the future Dapp developers won't need to know what they are, so the general users will never interact with them. Having said that, I'm not sure where else they'd fit into the model. (Perhaps "Consensus"?)

Comment: Add "UDP" for transport. (For node discovery.)

Comment: Add "Gitter" for social.

Comment: @RichardHorrocks thanks, great comments. re RLPx and devP2P - [I'm stll getting my head around exactly what they are and how they fit together](http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/12290/what-is-the-distinction-between-libp2p-devp2p-and-rlpx).

Comment: @RichardHorrocks re Geth, Parity etc in UX/UI. My thinking is that, whilst they implement protocols at lower layers, they can me thought of as different rules for presenting informaton to the user.

Comment: @RichardHorrocks made it a community wiki and added your suggestions...

Comment: I saw [this](https://twitter.com/mwilcox/status/876582579415076864), which seems to be a [t-shirt design from 1999](http://stuff.halibut.com/stuff/9layer_big.html)!

Answer (score 1):

It's not quite the same thing in that it uses a different form of abstraction, but there's a Consensys tool called [EthOn](https://github.com/ConsenSys/EthOn) that provides a way to visualise data flows within Ethereum in an [ontological](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ontology_%28information_science%29) way, using Web Ontology Language ([OWL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_Ontology_Language)).

Example illustrations can be found at [this](https://github.com/ConsenSys/EthOn/blob/master/EthOn_illustrations.md) link.

It was first described in [this](https://media.consensys.net/ethon-introducing-semantic-ethereum-15f1f0696986#.9m67kudm8) Medium post.

Answer (score 0):

A wiki version, including Rob Hitchens' and Richard Horrocks' suggestions:

```
| Layer        | Ethereum Blockchain Protocols                                              |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

| Governance   | EIP process, Influencer announcements and social consensus                 |

| Social       | Github, Gitter, Reddit, SE, Slack, Word of Mouth etc                       |

| UX/UI        | Geth, Parity, PyEthApp, Mist, browser+nodejs+web3, etherscan etc           |

| Consensus    | Block derivation and PoW (Yellow Paper)                                    |

| Application  | Kademlia, RPC, IPC                                                         |

| Presentation | AES, ECDSA                                                                 |

| Session      | DevP2P, RLPx                                                               |

| Transport    | TCP, UDP (discovery)                                                       |

| Network      | As public internet                                                         |

| Data Link    | As public internet                                                         |

| Physical     | As public internet                                                         |
```